# JSON - Serialize pandas dataframe with numpy arrays entries

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, serialization

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` with `numpy.ndarray`s entries (of different sizes). How can I serialize it to json?

It seems that pandas doesn't support serialization of ndarrays at the moment:

```
pandas.DataFrame([{'a': numpy.array(1)}, {'a': numpy.array((1,2))}]).to_json()
TypeError: array(1) (0d array) is not JSON serializable at the moment
```

**Closely related questions whose answers won't solve my problem:**

[Storing Dataframe with Array Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39802438/storing-dataframe-with-array-entries): I can't use the nice trick there because my dataframe consists of arrays with varying sizes.

[Convert numpy type to python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27050108/convert-numpy-type-to-python): If there was a way to use MyEncoder in `DataFrame.to_json()`

Answer (score -1):

You can of course use `to_pickle()`

Comment: True, but I would really prefer json as it is the most readable serialization I know.
I updated now my question to be specifically about json. Thanks

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.